# change TextField label position

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, position, uitextfield, styled-components

I'm trying to change the position of a label in TextFiled without configure my whole project to be rlt like I've seen here on other questions. I just want to change it in style and only for this component. I've tried many examples here but found none that works or suit my need.
I succeeded in positioning the label text to the right, but the space in the border is still on the left as shown [here](https://ibb.co/S3jJfXd)

This is the code I wrote:

```
  const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    labelRoot: {
      right: '10px',
    },
    shrink: {
      transformOrigin: 'top right',
      transform: 'translateX(50px)',
    },
  }));
  const classes = useStyles();


<TextField 
     label='שם לקוח'
     InputLabelProps={{classes: {root: classes.labelRoot, shrink: classes.shrink},}}/>
```

EDIT: I tried to use Steve Gomez suggestion but it still didn't work:

```
import React from 'react';
import {create} from 'jss';
import rtl from 'jss-rtl';
import {createTheme, ThemeProvider} from '@mui/material/styles';
import {jssPreset, StylesProvider} from '@mui/styles';

// Configure JSS
const jss = create({plugins: [...jssPreset().plugins, rtl()]});

const theme = createTheme({
  direction: 'rtl',
});

function RTL(props) {
  return (
    <StylesProvider jss={jss}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <div dir='rtl'>{props.children}</div>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </StylesProvider>
  );
}

export default RTL;

....

<RTL>code here</RTL>
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be an easier way to do this, and the juice may not be worth the squeeze for your particular case, but you can use [MUI's Right-to-Left Guide](https://v4.mui.com/guides/right-to-left/#3-jss-rtl) in conjunction with it's [Nested Theming](https://v4.mui.com/customization/theming/#nesting-the-theme) functionality to support this use case.

*I realize that you said that you only "want to change it in style", but I thought I'd provide this as an alternative option in case none of the other answers that you receive for this question are satisfactory.*

In a nutshell, to use this method you'll need to:

1. Install [jss-rtl](https://github.com/alitaheri/jss-rtl)
2. Create a nested theme to wrap the RTL field with `direction: "rtl"`.
3. And create/configure instances of `StylesProvider` and `ThemeProvider` (as described in the nesting docs -- ***NOTE:** these instances will be nested inside of the existing `ThemeProvider` that you're already using for your app.*).
4. Wrap your component in an RTL element such as `<div dir="rtl">`
5. Use your newly created RTL `Textfield` as you normally would.

Code excerpt:

```
import rtl from "jss-rtl";
import { StylesProvider, jssPreset } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const jss = create({ plugins: [...jssPreset().plugins, rtl()] });

const theme = createTheme({
  direction: "rtl"
});

...

<StylesProvider jss={jss}>
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <div dir="rtl">
      <TextField
        label="שם לקוח"
        variant="outlined"
        InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
        fullWidth
      />
    </div>
  </ThemeProvider>
</StylesProvider>
```

All of that should produce something to the effect of:

[image: image of nested RTL component in form]

Working CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-61uc5i?file=/demo.js

*(FYI I assumed you are using MUI 4 because of your use of `makeStyles()`, but this can be accomplished with MUI 5 as well.)*

### **Updated Answer with Reusable Component:**

To answer a follow-up question, to make this a reusable component what would require not additional styling, you could create this as a wrapper component that could be used as follows:

```
export const RTLWrapper = ({ children }) => (
  <StylesProvider jss={jss}>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <div dir="rtl">{children}</div>
    </ThemeProvider>
  </StylesProvider>
);

...

<RTLWrapper>
  <TextField
    label="שם לקוח"
    variant="outlined"
    InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
    fullWidth
  />
</RTLWrapper>

...

<RTLWrapper>
  <FormControl component="fieldset">
    <FormLabel component="legend">RTL Options</FormLabel>
      <FormGroup>
        <FormControlLabel
          control={<Checkbox name="gilad" />}
          label="Gilad Gray"
        />
        <FormControlLabel
          control={<Checkbox name="jason" />}
          label="Jason Killian"
        />
        <FormControlLabel
          control={<Checkbox name="antoine" />}
          label="Antoine Llorca"
        />
      </FormGroup>
    <FormHelperText>Helper Text</FormHelperText>
  </FormControl>
</RTLWrapper>
```

Which would produce:

[image: RTL wrapper example]

Working CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-8gvpx5?file=/demo.js:2678-3447

Comment: I want to use it on a couple of components througout my code, is there a chance to make it a reusable component? make a component named RTL which inside are prop children and then I just import it and use it's HTML tag <RTL> outside my code?

Comment: Or how do I use what I wrote in the beginning as a reusable scss component?

Comment: @OfirSasson Yes you can! You can write an RTL wrapper component using this method and then use it to wrap any components (not just Textfields) that you need to use with RTL support.

Answer (score 0):

### If you are looking for a fast answer to go: (also works for older MUI versions)

```
<TextField
  label="שם לקוח"
  sx={{
    "& label": {
      left: "unset",
      right: "1.75rem",
      transformOrigin: "right",
      fontSize: "0.8rem",
    },
    "& legend": {
      textAlign: "right",
      fontSize: "0.6rem",
    },
  }}
/>
```

### Full Explanation

Just like almost every other Material-UI component, `TextField` is made up of some different parts. You found and changed `label`, but the part responsible for the border space is called `legend`. You need to change that too.

### Approaches

Now we should think which approach we want to make in order to achieve these changes.

1. To change **all instances** of a component in the project globally, use **[theme](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/#api)**.
2. To have **only one specific component** change, use **[sx](https://mui.com/system/getting-started/the-sx-prop/)** props. [like the fast answer provided at the top]
3. To have a new customized component with the **reusability option**, use **[MUI  styled()](https://mui.com/system/styled/#api)**.

I noticed that you are using *MUI v4*. `makeStyles` is a legacy function that is not supported in *MUI v5* anymore. So I recommend upgrading to v5 and using `styled` instead.

```
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";

const StyledTextField = styled(TextField)({
  "& label": {
    left: "unset",
    right: "1.75rem",
    transformOrigin: "right",
    fontSize: "0.8rem",
  },
  "& legend": {
    textAlign: "right",
    fontSize: "0.6rem",
  },
});

export default function Example() {
  return (
    <>
      <StyledTextField label="שם לקוח" />
      <StyledTextField label="component2" />
    </>
  );
}
```

Using the first two approaches doesn't need upgrading MUI version to 5. So if you can't upgrade your MUI version for any reason, You can use them without any worries.

Answer (score -1):

I used both of Steve and Hamed answers and found something I'm satisfied with:

```
const sx = {
    '& label': {
      transformOrigin: 'right !important',
      left: 'inherit !important',
      right: '1.75rem !important',
    },
    '& legend': {
      textAlign: 'right',
    },
    '&  .MuiFormHelperText-root.Mui-error': {
      textAlign: 'right',
    },
  };

<TextField
         label='שם לקוח'
         onChange={(e) => onChangeValue('clientName', e.target.value)}
         error={error.scopeNameError !== ''}
         helperText={error.clientNameError}
         sx={sx}/>
```